# Disable and enable parent scroll based on recycler view visibility

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an Edittext. When the user clicks on it, I show up suggestions in a recycler view based on the keyword typed. The parent view containing the edittext (alongwith other items) is scrollable. I want the parent scrolling to be disabled when the recycler view is visible, and the enable again when the recycler view is invisible.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
..
..
..
..
</EditText


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/mentions_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ScrollView>
```

When the recycler view is visible as a dropdown of the edittext, how to disable the main parent scrollview.?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

 public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

private boolean enableScrolling = true;

public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
    return enableScrolling;
}

public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
    this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
}

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
   if (isEnableScrolling()) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
   } else {
       return false;
   }
 }
 }
```

and make xml like this

```
<yourpackage.MyScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
```

..
   ..
   ..
   ..

```
</yourpackage.MyScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/mentions_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and as per your requirement you can enable or disable your scroll
like this

```
MyScrollView myScrollView = (MyScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
if(yourrecyclerview adapter item count > 0)//or you can make condition like if(yourrecyclerview.isShown())
{
   myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(false); 
}else
{
    myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(true);
}
```

Comment: This should only disable the parent scrollview, but at the same time recycler view scroll is also disabled which should be enabled.

Comment: this is because your recycler view inside this custom scrollview make outside it.,show updated answer

Comment: Need a version of this where recyclerview is INSIDE scrollview and only scrollview gets disabled, not recyclerview.